# ui bootstrap datepicker inside an accordion is not visible

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to do a module with a datepicker inside an accordion.

problem is the datepicker popup box is not visible over the accordion.

here is a plunker showing the problem :

http://plnkr.co/edit/jBqU0LXQFcUuzQLency2?p=preview

any idea on how i could make the dialog window appear over the accordion module ?

**edit**: with bootstrap 3, this is working :

```
.panel-group .panel {
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Think you may have almost answered your own question, I think you want to use the dialog component in bootstrap UI mixed with the date picker to get the desired results.

Comment: @shaunhusain i was using the dialog component with the previous version of ui-bootstrap (0.4) because there was no datepickerPopup. but now it exists, i would prefer to use this datepickerPopup. it's nicer.

Comment: Your bootstrap 3 "edit" did the trick for me - for datepicker and typeahead, and it even collapses nicely when closing the accordian. big thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this css after the bootstrap.css link can fix it. This will override the CSS relating to `position` for each `accordion-body`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .collapse {
        position: inherit;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: it's working. thanks. just to understand, do you know why do they make the default `.collapse {position: relative;}` ?

Comment: @desgnl Not sure. This is a bit hacky and they should improve the compatibility of stylesheets. But for right now, this alternative should do the job and in the future there might be a better solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me Bootstrap version 3:

```
.panel-body {
  overflow: inherit !important;
}
```

my datepicker is in an accordion that is in a bootbox.