# AngularJS Datepicker not displaying totally on Bootstrap 3 Collapse/Accordion

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and the AngularJS UI. 
I've integrated a Datepicker into an accordion, but it doesn't show over/outside the accordion body in itself.

I found a reference on the same problem and the solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522042/ui-bootstrap-datepicker-inside-an-accordion-is-not-visible)), but it's with Bootstrap 2.3.1 and after trying the .collapse{ position:inherited; } solution on my code and trying to override the z-index, it's still not working.

Here's [a Plunker with the problem on 2.3.1](http://plnkr.co/edit/jBqU0LXQFcUuzQLency2?p=preview) so you can understand the problem, and my current code. Any ideas on what's causing the problem?

```
<div class="row ix-advanced">
    <div class="panel-group col-md-12" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="advancedSearch" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <label><?php echo _t('Date')?></label><br />
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" placeholder="<?php echo _t('From')?>"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                        <label><?php echo _t('To')?></label><br />
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="<?php echo _t('To')?>">
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css, overwrite bootstrap's panel `overflow: hidden` property with

```
.panel-group .panel {
overflow: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add to the last datepicker the following attribute:

```
datepicker-append-to-body="true"
```

You may also want to change the attribute "open" to "is-open".

You can see the results in the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0xoahBxLzbE7KwimA61I?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Fs6vCciXRRc7GeUwyR2?p=preview) to the latest versions and it seems to work fine.

My problem though is that if you layout your controls with the grid system, then the popup is clipped to fit the row and col-

-Stephen